# dispatch_group_leave never called in managed object context performBlock API

Tags: core-data, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a core data based app, now try to using `NSManagedObjectContext` block based API. The context is private queue type, enqueue a async block for insert and save objects, but before execution continue, i need to wait save to complete, so create a `dispatch group` object to monitor, but the `dispatch_group_leave` never called after save operation in block, the `dispatch_group_wait` won't return, that's weird. And if i remove `save` method, this will be called, if add `dispatch group`, the `save` method seemly never be return, there is also no any error log information.

My test example code:

```
__block dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);

[self.privateContext performBlock:^{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Tester *t = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tester" inManagedObjectContext:self.privateContext];

        t.timestamp = [NSDate date];
        t.identifier = [@(i) stringValue];
    }

    NSError *er2 = nil;

    if (![self.privateContext save:&er2])
        NSLog(@"%@", er2);

    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the save operation in a `@try/@finally` and putting the `dispatch_group_leave(group);` in the `@finally`? `-save:` could be throwing an exception.

Comment: Also, for the example you have here, why not just use `-performBlockAndWait:`?

Comment: @ipmcc Because the data to load is ver large and consume memory, performBlock encapsulate a autorelease pool, which is conveniance. I still don't know why save method no any reation and don't return. Apple on WWDC 2012 core data session introduced this notion.

Comment: performBlock does more than just an autorelease pool. See http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93355099502/performblock-vs-performblockandwait